# Duplicating attribute table in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes

I have an attribute table with a lot of fields that I added for data collected via gps. I would now like to duplicate that attribute table for use with another layer, based on different data.

Is there a simple way to do this other than manually?

I am using QGIS.

Answer (score 3):

You can create data relation or join tables by unique field (point id or similar). Join can be exported as new vector file:

1. **Join** attribute tables (`layer properties --> Join`) see: [Another Way to Join a New Column to a DBF if OpenOffice is Giving a "Longer Than the Number of Digits Allowed" Error?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/119497/another-way-to-join-a-new-column-to-a-dbf-if-openoffice-is-giving-a-longer-than/119530#119530)
2. **Data Relations** `(Project --> Project Properties --> Relations`) see: [Editing feature attribute values in joined non-spatial table in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/229466/editing-feature-attribute-values-in-joined-non-spatial-table-in-qgis/229501#229501)